M.D.A and distance from runway
Is there any standard distance from runway that corresponds to M.D.A for airliners?
I mean is there a rule or pattern as to a typical distance from runway where M.D.A is reached? Example 2.5 NM from RWY corresponds to your M.D.A?

Reached. Is there a typical distance from RWY TDZE that M.D.A should bz reached,. I.e at around 3.5 or 4 NM from TDZE, you normally should have reached  the M.D.A? On another topic, can you help regarding the case of circle to land if A.P is off for LFMN 04R? What would be the procedure in such a case?

There is no standard or typical distance for reaching the MDA. It depends on a lot of factors:

Where exactly is the descent from the platform altitude initiated?
How steep is the descent?
How high is the MDA?

All of these could be different depending on the approach and how the approach is flown.
For example, let us look at two non-precision approaches into runway 34 at LGKR:

The VOR approaches have an MDA of 2000':

This approach should be flown as a CDFA, where the descent from 2900' is initiated at 7.9 NM from the runway at an angle of 3.4°. This would result in reaching 2000' at ~5.4 NM from the runway.
However, when descending already at the FAF [FD34], which is 8.1 NM from the runway, you would reach 2000' at ~5.6 NM. If you would further change the descent angle to the standard 3°, you would reach 2000' at ~5.3 NM.

The RNP approach to the same runway has an MDA of only 770':

Here you fly the CDFA from a stepdown altitude of 1700' at 3°, resulting in reaching 770' at ~2.3 NM from the runway.



Formula for calculating the distance to the runway where MDA is reached:
$$ \text{MDA Distance} = \text{Start Distance} - \frac{\text{Start Altitude} - \text{MDA}}{\tan(\text{descent angle})} $$

Thanks. Does this work even if approach is not in straight line. Coming back to my visual approach on LFMN04R where I start my descent with F.P.A 3° radial 354 to CGS vOR and turning to final 43°. And lastly, can we talk about circling approach if AP is off? I'd like to understand if we're visual and use MDA set for precision approach to do a circle to land when AP is off makes sense and whether it's possible

Let's not mix different topics, please. In general, this formula will only apply to straight approaches. Otherwise, the direct distance to the runway is not the same as the actual flight path length. However, the first part of the answer still applies to circling approaches.

Can you give an examlke for the calculation? Distance is in NM and altitude in feet so I'm not able to make the conversion.
